# Django Public and private posts

Tags: django, django-models

I was trying to implement the public and private posts features for that i've created `is_private` in models and check it's values if it's true or false. Based on that i want to display private and public posts.`(E.x if is_private is set to false then posts should be visible to all user and if it is private then should be visible to only authenticated user..

````
models.py 

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class post_model(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_private = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title + "\n" + self.description```
````

```
views.py 

@login_required(login_url='/login')
def home(request):
    form = post_form(request.POST or None)
    posts = post_model.objects.all()
    if form.is_valid():
        posts = post_model.objects.all().values('is_private')

        for post in posts:
          if post['is_private']:
              posts = posts.exclude(is_private=False)
          else:
              posts = posts.exclude(is_private=True)
    else:
        form = post_form()
    return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'posts': posts, 'form': form})
```

```
forms.py 

from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from . models import post_model

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

class post_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = post_model
        fields = ['title','description','is_private']
```

```
post.html

{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block title%}Create Post{% endblock %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{%block content%} 
<div class="container" style="align-items: center;">
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
     <div class="text-center mt-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Post</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

At this point it render public and private posts for all users...So how can i restrict the user from others ?

Comment: Are you sure about the logic in your views.py? You seem to first filter manually and then filter using the exclude function. You probably should only do one (i.e. using `.exclude` based on if the user is logged in, not based on the `is_private` status of the posts).

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with session authentication,
you should use the is_authenticated to verify if user is acuthenticated such as

```
if request. user.is_authenticated:
# Do something for authenticated users.
...
else:
# Do something for anonymous users.
```

for your case, I would do something like

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def home(request):
form = post_form(request.POST or None)
posts = post_model.objects.all()
if form.is_valid():
    posts = post_model.objects.all().values('is_private')

    if user.is_authenticated:
        posts=post_model.objects.all().filter(is_private=True)
    else:
        post=post_model.objects.all().filter(is_private=False)
   
else:
    form = post_form()
return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'posts': posts, 'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. However, the provided solution is not functioning as desired. It is displaying both public and private posts for all users.